# Redshift Unload with Grant or Canned ACL

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

is there a way to do an unload statement from redshift and pass the canned ACL `bucket-owner-full-control` ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having a separate bash script which adds proper ACL on the files created by Redshift.

```bash
S3_BUCKET="bla"
UNLOAD_FOLDER="path/to/bla"
for i in $(aws s3 ls s3://${S3_BUCKET}/${UNLOAD_FOLDER}/ --recursive | awk '{ print $4}');
    do  echo $i ;
        aws  s3api put-object-acl --bucket %s --region us-east-1 --key $i --acl bucket-owner-full-control;
    done
done
```